# Setting methodInfo.IsDefined() to true with C#

Tags: c#, attributes, methodinfo

I have a methodInfo from mymethod method of Example class.

```
internal class Example
{
    public static void mymethod(string str1, ref string str2, out string str3)
    {
        ....


MethodInfo mm = typeof(Example).GetMethod("mymethod");
```

How can I make an attribute (for example, ABCAttribute) of mm so that

```
mm.IsDefined(typeof(ABCAttribute), true)
```

becomes true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ABCAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then apply it to your method.

```
internal class Example
{
    [ABC]
    public static void mymethod(string str1, ref string str2, out string str3)
    {
    }
}
```